# Convert Keys & Values in Dictionary<int, string> to a String[] Array

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery-ui

I have a webservice function that returns something like the following:

- New Orleans, Louisiana
- New York, New York
- Newark, New Jersey

This data comes from the following function:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string[] GetCitiesWithState(string isoalpha2, string prefixText)
{
    var dict = AtomicCore.CityObject.GetCitiesInCountryWithStateAutocomplete(isoalpha2, prefixText);
    string[] cities = dict.Values.ToArray();
    return cities;
}
```

It works wonderfully, but what I really need **is a list like this**:

- 12, New Orleans, Louisiana
- 22, New York, New York
- 48, Newark, New Jersey

With the # being the City Id (this is contained with `dict`, which is type of: `Dictionary<int, string>`).

The reason I am doing this is because I have some Jquery that reads an ASMX service and this method, and I need to be able to see the City Id of the selected city.  This is my Jquery for clarity (which works currently):

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var parameters = {
                    isoalpha2: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString()%>',
                    prefixText: request.term
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AtomicService/Assets.asmx/GetCitiesWithState")%>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.each(data.d, function (index, value) {
                            return {
                                label: value,
                                value: index
                            }
                        }));
                    }

                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#<%=txtState.ClientID%>').val(ui.value);
            },
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 500
        });
```

Finally, what I am actually trying to achieve is when the user selects the city in the autocomplete which is hanging from: `$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>')`, I'd like the Jquery to split the value (e.g. New Orleans, Louisiana into two (New Orleans) and (Louisiana)), I'd then like 'New Orleans' to be the value of `$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>')` and 'Louisiana' to be the value of `$('#<%=txtState.ClientID%>')`... Any assistance getting this crazyness to work is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you clearly, you just need to return the data from the WebMethod a bit differently:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string[] GetCitiesWithState(string isoalpha2, string prefixText)
{
    var dict = AtomicCore.CityObject.GetCitiesInCountryWithStateAutocomplete(isoalpha2, prefixText);
    string[] response = dict.Select(x => String.Format("{0}, {1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToArray();
    return response;
}
```

And now, at JavaScript side, you need to split the string into `index` and `label` manually (because what `index` is now is just a line number, I believe). Something like that (just a draft):

```
response($.each(data.d, function (index, value) {
    return {
        label: value.slice(value.indexOf(',')),
        value: parseInt(value.split(',')[0])
     }
 }));
```

Comment: Super answer A. :)  Thanks very much. The LINQ is particularly effective!